# React Update Props From Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<PARENT>` component with state called `map`:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    map: {
      group1: [],
    },
  };
}
```

And in `componentWillMount`, I `setState` for the `group1` with an array of elements. Then in a `<CHILD>` component's render, I render that `group1` array of elements.

I did it this way because I'd like to keep the array from re-rendering every little update to the parent state.

Each of the element in the array is clickable. When clicked, it updates parent's state and re-render only the clicked element.

```
export const handleClickRank = (options, i, group, rank, preset) => {
  component = options.component;
  const newState = update(component.state, { range: { current: { ranks: { [rank]: { $set: preset } } } },
                                             map: { [group]: { [i]: { 0: { props: { toggled: { $set: preset } } } } } } });
  component.setState(newState);
};
```

The `range` state above is needed to update the `current` `ranks`. I thought I could leave it there and somehow magically update the clicked element. Or atleast update the whole array. But it doesn't do that which I understand. I thought about adding `shouldComponentUpdate` but I read that can become a mess real quick and avoid if possible. So I added a second update to state (of `<PARENT>`) which is the `update(component.state, { map: { [group]: { [i]: { 0: { props: { toggled: { $set: preset } } } } } } });` portion.

What this does is `setState` on `<PARENT>`'s `map` state and finds the clicked index, and changes the `props` of `toggled` to new value. Now it updates only the clicked element. And it does this pretty much the way I want it do.

**(here's my question)** I read that updating props is an anti-pattern and should be avoided. However, what I think I'm doing here is sending different props from the parent to child so I don't see a harm in that. Am I wrong for thinking this?

Comment: You're *way* overthinking this. Setting state is not the same thing as mutating props. Setting new state is exactly the correct thing to do.

Comment: You're not right about not wanting to mutate props, but you definitely can copy them into state, and then work internally with component state.

Comment: Thank you both, I just got tripped up because of the name props in the map state. Your explanations were very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Also it's worth mentioning `shouldComponentUpdate` can be pretty helpful on optimizing your compontents a bit. Where you can tell the component to update or not, instead of react figuring out if there's a DOM difference.